# Numpy Matrix to tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, numpy, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

**How to display a Numpy matrix, as a bitmap, into a Tkinter canvas?**
More precisely, how to fill a `PhotoImage` with content from a matrix?

```
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)
self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.swharden.com/wp/2010-06-24-fast-tk-pixelmap-generation-from-2d-numpy-arrays-in-python/) is working solution, slightly modified to make it work (some function was deprecated) and to simplify it to keep only the necessary part. We have to use `Image.frombytes(...)` to read the data in the numpy matrix.

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy

class mainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.root, width=500, height=400)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self.frame, width=500,height=400)
        self.canvas.place(x=-2,y=-2)
        data=numpy.array(numpy.random.random((400,500))*100,dtype=int)
        self.im=Image.frombytes('L', (data.shape[1],data.shape[0]), data.astype('b').tostring())
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.photo,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
        self.root.update()
        self.root.mainloop()

mainWindow()
```

Comment: You can get there even quicker with `im=Image.fromarray(data)`

Comment: @Basj an answer to what? There's no question. But it seems unneccessary to convert the ndarray to a string and back. Related: 
http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray

Comment: then improve your answer by replacing `self.im=Image.frombytes('L', (data.shape[1],data.shape[0]), data.astype('b').tostring())` with `self.im=Image.fromarray(data)` Oh and you actually do not need `im` to be a member of `self`. Keeping a reference to `photo` is the only important part, since it may otherwise get garbage collected. 
Furthermore, it seems to be standard to store those references into e.g. `self.canvas._foo`

Your snipped indeed helped me.

Comment: @nitzel Feel free to modify the answer with your propositions, or post another answer. I really think it's helpful to have 2 versions, so we can compare, etc. Thanks.

Comment: If you wish alternate, low-level solution bringing no dependency on external modules (like ImageTk), see https://python-forum.io/Thread-Tkinter-createing-a-tkinter-photoimage-from-array-in-python3